# Ubuntu14.04 LTS Duplicated Applications in /usr/share/applications

Tags: .desktop, ibus

I did `sudo apt-get purge ibus`, after which some system setting options disappeared. I solved that by install the `ubuntu-desktop` package.

However, after I reinstalled the iBus, some applications(Backups, Bluetooth, Color,... [show in the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY8DF.png)) in the folder: `/usr/share/applications` become duplicated.

Output of:

- [`dpkg -S /usr/share/applications/*`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12332606/)
- [`/usr/share/applications$ ls`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12332658/)

Answer (score 1):

They have the same name, but the **different Command** (*found by right-click, in properties*). One for **gnome-control-center**-applicationname, the other for **unity-control-center**-applicationname. And the name in the Dash is direct to **gnome**. Don know which one is better, I will delete the **unity-control-center**, which seems not in use... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Nautilus resolve `.desktop` file name be reading the `Name` defined inside it. It does not use the real filename. Also it is not possible to have same file name in the EXT file system.

Use this command to see the reals names and the corresponding package name it comes from:

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/applications/*
```

As expected, all duplicate  you have are from control center. Ubuntu had forked `gnome-control-center` with 14.04 release, it does install separate package `unity-control-center`.

You may like to remove Gnome one if you have only Unity install (or the inverse). But you don't have to, they will not appear in dash.

Comment: All duplicated applications come from the unity-control-center. But the comment just show only one of the duplicated applications:                             (unity-control-center: /usr/share/applications/unity-appearance-panel.desktop
unity-control-center: /usr/share/applications/unity-bluetooth-panel.desktop
unity-control-center: /usr/share/applications/unity-color-panel.desktop
) these are the duplicated ones(color, bluetooth, display, files, mouse & touchpad, network, universal access, user accounts, wacom tablet, system settings)

Comment: @BruceYo , Could you post the full output to http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Please find output in paste.ubuntu.com: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12332606/

Comment: /usr/share/applications$ ls: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12332658/

Comment: Hi, just found they have the same name, but the different Command. One for gnome-control-center-applicationname, the other for unity-control-center-applicationname. And the name in the Dash is for gnome. I will delete the unity-control-center... Thanks!